# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.javatest.entity.User'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with my UserController,when I want realize method findOne in UserController it tells me "Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'javatest.entity.User".

I wanted to fix by myself, but I don't understand what this means. Could you please help me with this issue.
Thanks

```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.javatest.entity.User;
import com.javatest.repository.UserRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<User> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{username}")
    public User find(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        return repository.findOne(username);  \\error here
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{username}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        repository.delete(username);\\error
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/{username}")
    public User update(@PathVariable("username") String username, @RequestBody User user)  {
        if (repository.exists(username)) {
            user.setUsername(username); \\error
            return repository.save(user);
        } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What type of `id` does `User` have?

Comment: It doesn't have any id. I just want to fetch by username not by id

Comment: Are you using `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository`?

Comment: @tdranv JpaRepository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calling most of your methods under the inteface`QueryByExampleExecutor<T>`, where the method parameter is typically of type `Example`. For example, `findOne()` is defined as

```
<S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);
```

and you are passing in username as `String`, which isn't a generic type where `S` is a type/subtype of `T` (`User`) in your case, hence the error.

To fix, you want to define a method called `findByUsername` under your `JpaRepository`. Do so for other methods as well.